# How to replace part of awk command by a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I have the following `awk` command that works...

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="</a>"; ORS=RS"\n"} /<p>Test2<\/p>/' file
```

But now I need to replace `Test2` by a shell script variable.

I've tried using `-v` option like below, but without success

```
awk -v ss="Test2" 'BEGIN{RS="</a>"; ORS=RS"\n"} /<p>{print ss}<\/p>/' file
```

As I told above, I'm using this command in a script, so I've tried to replace using directly my script variable, without success too...

```
AWK_SEARCH="Test2"
awk 'BEGIN{RS="</a>"; ORS=RS"\n"} /<p>${AWK_SEARCH}<\/p>/' file
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: If you `export AWK_SEARCH` then in the awk you can use `ENVIRON["AWK_SEARCH"]`, but @EdMorton's answer is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v tgt="Test2" 'BEGIN{RS="</a>"; ORS=RS"\n"; tgt="<p>"tgt"</p>"} $0 ~ tgt' file
```

Modifying the variable in the BEGIN section is much more efficient than concatenating then testing the string once per input line.

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you're looking for :

```
 var="test2"; #dynamic content, you can set it to "$1" and pass the value as 
 #argument to script
 awk -v awk_var="$var" '
 BEGIN{RS="</a>"; ORS=RS"\n"}
 $0 ~ "<p>"awk_var"</p>"' 37095194.txt
```

Comment: @John1024 : Thanks for that ! Corrected :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'unquote' your script variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
AWK_SEARCH="Test2"
awk 'BEGIN{RS="</a>"; ORS=RS"\n"} /<p>'"${AWK_SEARCH}"'<\/p>/' file
```

It's 'stopping' the awk quotes right before the script variable, enclosing the script variable in double quotes, and then 'continuing' the awk quotes right after the script variable (at least that's how I think of it).

Comment: No. Never do this it is 100% wrong the wrong approach as it expands the value of the shell variable to become part of the text of the awk script before the awk interpreter sees it which can lead to all sorts of cryptic failures given the possible values of that shell variable. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.